# Main menu links not working on Wordpress

Tags: wordpress, permalinks

The main menu links on my site are not working. When I click on any of them, rather than take me to the correct page, they just take me to the homepage again.

When I hover over the links, the correct page's address shows up. So I know the permalinks are correct.

I tried disabling all of my plugins, reinstalling my theme, a different theme and nothing has worked yet. The only thing that worked was changing the permalink settings to "plain." However I would prefer not to use the "plain" option  since I have a lot of things linked internally that use the "custom" option and it would mean I'd have to re-write everything.

Any ideas to what's going on? Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Is mod_rewrite available on your server, and are you allowed to use it?

Comment: I don't have access to the server my page is on. It's owned by the parent company of my company. Why?

Comment: Because WordPress implements "pretty URLs" based on mod_rewrite. (I am not sure if it has a fallback for when mod_rewrite is not available.)

Comment: Good to know. I'll see if I can get access. Do you know why it might have stopped working? It was working fine a few days ago.

Comment: Perhaps the server admin changed some setting … probably best if you talk to them directly.